# How to keep a navbar collapsed across server round trips?

Tags: html, navbar

my navbar looks like this:

```
        <nav id = "nav" class="navbar-primary">
            <ul class="navbar-primary-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/home"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/link1"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/link2"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I am collapsing the navbar using JS:

```
function navbar(){
  $('.navbar-primary').toggleClass('collapsed');
};
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-primary.collapsed {
  width: 55px;
}
```

I am using a browser storage to store a variable to remember if the user collapsed the navbar. here's that piece:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var navbar_state = localStorage.getItem('navbar_state');

  if( navbar_state == 'collapsed'){
      console.log('collapsed found... collapsing on document ready');
      $('.navbar-primary').toggleClass('collapsed');
  };
}
```

This all works great, except for the fact that after every roundtrip, the navbar shows expanded fully for a split second, then my code runs and it is being collapsed. How can I keep it fully collapsed over server round trips?

Comment: you can't - unless you use a server side language to add a class based on a cookie - if you are using js, you are always going to get a FOUC whilst the dom is loaded and before the js kicks in, the best you could do in this case is start it closed then open it when the js kicks in (if it needs to open)

Comment: @Pete - thanks for your answer! Any recommendation on how to do it using your suggested approach?

Comment: you could start off with your collapsed class on as default and then do your local storage check and then remove the collapsed class if needed - that way it should start hidden and then show if it is needed, then you won't get that flash if it is not needed